# PHP write a portion of a current file to new file

Tags: php

I have a php file which contains both PHP code and HTML Tags.

The actual content of the portion which I want to save to a new file.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>PayPal PHP SDK: Transaction Search Results</title>
    <link href="sdk.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <br>
    <center>
    <font size=3 color=black face=Verdana><b>Transaction Search Results</b></font>
    <br><br>
    <table class="api">
<?php //checking for Transaction ID in NVP response
 if(!isset($resArray["L_TRANSACTIONID0"])){
?>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="6" class="field">
            No Transaction Selected
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php 
  }else { 
        $count=0;
        //counting no.of  transaction IDs present in NVP response arrray.
        while (isset($resArray["L_TRANSACTIONID".$count])) 
            $count++; 
?>  
            <tr>
            <td colspan="6" class="thinfield">
                   Results 1 - <?php echo $count; ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td >
            </td>
            <td >
                <b>ID</b></td>
            <td >
                <b>Time</b></td>
            <td >
                <b>Status</b></td>
            <td >
                <b>Payer Name</b></td>
            <td >
                <b>Gross Amount</b></td>
        </tr>

<?php 
      $ID=0;
  while ($count>0) {
          $transactionID    = $resArray["L_TRANSACTIONID".$ID];
          $timeStamp = $resArray["L_TIMESTAMP".$ID];
          $payerName  = $resArray["L_NAME".$ID]; 
          $amount  = $resArray["L_AMT".$ID]; 
          $status  = $resArray["L_STATUS".$ID]; 
          $count--; $ID++;
?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $ID; ?></td>
            <td><a id="TransactionDetailsLink0"  href="TransactionDetails.php?transactionID=<?php echo $transactionID; ?>"><?php echo $transactionID; ?></a></td>
            <td><?php echo $timeStamp;?> <!--12/7/2005 9:57:58 AM--></td>
            <td><?php echo $status;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $payerName;?></td>
            <td>USD<?php echo $amount;?></td>
        </tr>
<?php }// while
}//else ?>

     </table>
    </center>
    <a class="home" id="CallsLink" href="index.html">Home</a>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried this like 
< just before the html.
Then in the end

```
<?php
$output = ob_get_clean();
file_put_contents (time().'response.html', $output);?>
```

But the result is, the output display is gone and no file is created.

Comment: You need to start the output buffer

Comment: Don't you forget `ob_start()` at the beginning of the file?

Comment: Yes I have added that, only by mistake left out in the question. Updated it. but still facing the same problem.

Comment: sorry I am getting the output_file correctly. what I was doing wrong is I was looking around `r` for response, where as the file being created was on the top for time portion was appended to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [start the output buffer](http://php.net/ob_start) for `ob_get_clean()` to return something.

```
<?php
ob_start();
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>PayPal PHP SDK: Transaction Search Results</title>
    <link href="sdk.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <br>
    <center>
....
```

Comment: is it possible to show the result in browser and write to file at the same time.

Comment: Yes. You can output the variable that is holding `ob_get_clean()`. For example,  `echo $output;`